# AWS CDK - Nested SNS Subscription filter policy

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, amazon-sns, aws-cdk-typescript

I have implemented a Subscription Filter Policy in my test account in SNS to only send data coming in a particular subfolder in S3 to my SQS queue. This is working exactly as expected

```
    {
  "Records": {
    "s3": {
      "object": {
        "key": [
          {
            "prefix": "test/test1"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "eventName": [
      {
        "prefix": "ObjectCreated:"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I am trying to implement the same Subscription policy using CDK but it is giving me below error.

CDK Code:

```
 topic.addSubscription(new subs.SqsSubscription(queue, {
  filterPolicyWithMessageBody: {
    "Records": {
      "s3": {
        "object": {
          "key": [
            {
              "prefix": "test/test1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventName": [
        {
          "prefix": "ObjectCreated:"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}))
```

Error:

```
     Type '{ s3: { object: { key: { prefix: string; }[]; }; }; eventName: { prefix: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FilterOrPolicy'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 's3' does not exist in type 'FilterOrPolicy'.
```